# Set data of the first option in a drop-down list

Tags: jquery

I have this option:

```
<select id="options">
   <option val="n_0" data-option-code="code_0">option 0</option>
   <!-- ... -->
</seclect>
```

When I do:

```
$("#options option:first").data('option-code', 'new-value');
```

It seems that nothing happens. I mean, I always have the same `data-option-code="code_0"`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $("#options option:first").attr('data-option-code', 'new-value');

Comment: `data()` does not change attribute. No different than setting a value on an input...you won't see the change in the html

Comment: You won't see the new value if you're looking at the source code. jQuery stores it internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data()` setter method adds information to jQuery's internal cache. It does not affect the DOM. If you use the getter of `data()` you'll see the information has been stored correctly, eg:

```
var foo = $("#options option:first").data('option-code'); // = 'new-value'
```

If you require the `data` attribute to be updated in the DOM, use `attr()`:

```
$("#options option:first").attr('data-option-code', 'new-value');
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help